# Boost 1.44 asio linker problems with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-asio, boost-system

I'm trying to build a project that needs Boost 1.44.0 in Visual Studio 2005 (I know it's old but I have to use these versions). I already have build it with bjam as it mention [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) with the following line in VS 2005 Command Prompt:

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-8.0 --build-type=complete link=static threading=multi architecture=x86 address-model=64 --with-system stage
```

I already set my library paths to:

```
...\boost_1_44_0\stage\lib
```

and for the include:

```
...\boost_1_44_0
```

But when I try to Build the whole solution, the linking process throws the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__getaddrinfo@16 referenced in function "class boost::system::error_code __cdecl boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::getaddrinfo(char const *,char const *,struct addrinfo const &,struct addrinfo * *,class boost::system::error_code &)" (?getaddrinfo@socket_ops@detail@asio@boost@@YA?AVerror_code@system@4@PBD0ABUaddrinfo@@PAPAU7@AAV564@@Z)  TAsioSocket.obj
```

and

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__freeaddrinfo@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::freeaddrinfo(struct addrinfo *)" (?freeaddrinfo@socket_ops@detail@asio@boost@@YAXPAUaddrinfo@@@Z) TAsioSocket.obj
```

I think it has to be something missing with the library generated but I dunno what (Maybe I missing a command input when I generated the Boost Libs?). I know **Asio** depends on **System**, but **libboost_system** is already generated. I try to search in the libs of */stage/lib* but the function **getaddrinfo** was unable to be found.

Comment: [`getaddrinfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a Windows API function. Maybe you're not linking to `Ws2_32.lib` (that's listed towards the bottom of the linked page)

Comment: ws2_32.lib is already in my additional dependencies with the WinDDK (_7600.16385.1_) library as well